# How to stack columns/series vertically in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe that looks something like this

```
entry_1      entry_2
2022-01-21   2022-02-01
2022-03-23   NaT
2022-04-13   2022-06-06
```

however I need to vertically stack my two columns to get something like this

```
entry
2022-01-21
2022-03-23
2022-04-13
2022-02-01
NaT
2022-06-06
```

I've tried using `df['entry'] = df['entry_1].append(df['entry_2']).reset_index(drop=True)` to no success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that you use

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.ravel(), columns=['all_entries'])
```

This will allow you to return the flattened underlying data as an ndarray. By wrapping that in `pd.Dataframe()` you will convert it back to a dataframe with the column name "all_entries"

For more information please visit the pandas doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ravel.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat of series and get the result in a dataframe like:

```
df['entry_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['entry_1'])
df['entry_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['entry_2'])
df_result = pd.DataFrame({
               'entry':pd.concat([df['entry_1'], df['entry_2']], ignore_index=True)
            })
```

or

```
entry_cols = ['entry_1', 'entry_2']
df_result = pd.DataFrame({
       'entry':pd.concat([df[col] for col in entry_cols], ignore_index=True)
 })
```

print(df_result)

```
       entry
0 2022-02-21
1 2022-02-23
2 2022-04-13
3 2022-02-01
4        NaT
5 2022-06-06
```